# How to change default engine in WAMP to InnoDB

Tags: innodb, myisam, wamp

Can someone tell me how to change my default storage engine to InnoDB using wamp? Currently it is MyISAM.

Answer (score 0):

Find mysql configuration file `my.ini`, find `default-storage-engine` setting line in `[mysqld]` section, insert/edit it to `default-storage-engine=INNODB`, save changes, restart server service.